# Run a jar in a Databricks notebook cell

Tags: java, azure-databricks

I'm totally new using Databricks (and in fact all Azure components).

Long story short:
I need to invoke a jar file like I do on my terminal.
Meaning something like
`java -jar C:\Windows\...\myjavaapp.jar javaClass configFile=C:\Windows\...\params.properties aParam1=True aParam2=Field1,Field2,Field3 aParam3=output.csv`

So this is how I'm running it on Windows terminal.
But now how to do this on a Databricks notebook cell? Is it possible? I already imported the `jar` file into my notebook libs.

locally I built a python app to run these commands, and it worked perfectly.
Is it possible to do it in Databricks? I tried, but no success. Don't know if it's something I'm doing it wrong, or it just doesn't work at all.
I need to do this kind of dyanmic, meaning I working with String manipulation where I build the different commands.

Hope I was clear with my question.

Thanks for your help and time!

EDIT:
here's the python function I'm using to run the command:

```
def java_run_command(command):
      try:
        print('Trying to running command ' + command)
        result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True, check=True, shell=True)
        output = result.stdout
        error = result.stderr
        if error:
          print(date_format_str() + " - Some errors were found: \n")
          print(error)
      except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
          print(date_format_str() + " - Error executing java command: \n")
          print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run jar files in databricks jobs, follow below steps.

Go To > **Workflows** and click on **Create Job**.

[image]

You will get interface like below, fill all the details and click on create.

[image]

**Task name** - Give a name to the task.
**Type** - Select the type. Here it is **JAR**.
**Main class** - Give the name of your class. Make sure you are giving correct name.
**Cluster** - Select the cluster on which your task should run.
**Dependent libraries** - Add your jar file here.
**Parameters** - Give parameters in the list.

After clicking on create you will get below page.

[image]

Here, click on **Run Now** and see details in **runs**.

[image]

and output.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Totally out of time, but this makes sense and solved my problem!